# XUnit change arguments based on environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, automated-tests, xunit

is there a way to change arguments in XUnit Theory based on environment?

I want to have different arguments for development and production environment for the same tests.

Is there some way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't a good pratice change de values for tests if it's unit tests. I think is the same for integration tests. But you can define values in appsetting for test project and get this values using ClassData.

```
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(ScenariosClass))]
    public void Method_Test(ScenariosClass data)
    {
     ....
    }
```

[Creating strongly typed xUnit theory test data with TheoryData](https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will look into that. Do you have example how to set appsetting and get the values using the ClassData?

Comment: 1. Add a appsettings.json at you test project path.
2. Add the json file on your csproj file. 
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="appsettings.json">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

3. Build an IConfiguration
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .Build();

4. Get you value
var configurationValue = config GetValue<string>("ConfigurationName");

Comment: Thnak you very much, yout solution is working :)